# Spring: not a managed type - separate test project

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-test, persistence.xml

Initially I built a Maven-Spring application with test cases. It worked well and all tests did pass. But now I have a separate maven project for tests and moved the test classes and the spring xml configuration files that project. 
I have added the main spring project as dependency.

I suppose the test project doesn't load the list of values defined in "packagesToScan" property in db-context.xml. Could anyone please help me find the error?

```
<!-- Entity Manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="m-entrevista" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
             <value>{com.packagename}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The project structure looks like this. 
**Spring test project**

[image]

**Main spring project**

[image]

When I run a test, it throws an IllegalArgumentException.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was **Persistence.xml** which triggered the exception. Initially I had the *persistence.xml* in my test project. As soon as I moved it into **Main Spring Persistece** project, where I have JPA Entities, all tests ran without any errors.